# How to use a single covariance matrix in GHMM?

Tags: python, c, numpy, machine-learning, hidden-markov-models

I am trying to train a Hidden Markov Model (HMM) using the [GHMM library](http://ghmm.sourceforge.net/). So far, I have been able to train both a discrete model, and a continuous model using a single Gaussian for each of the states.

There are really good examples on how to do it [here](http://nullege.com/codes/show/src@g@h@ghmm-HEAD@trunk@ghmm@ghmmwrapper@examples@continuousHMM.py/12/ghmm.HMMFromMatrices/python).

However, I would like to train a continuous HMM with a **single** covariance matrix tied across all states (instead of having one for each state). Is that possible with GHMM lib? If it is, I would love to see some examples. If not, could somebody point me to some other code, or refer me to another HMM python/c library that can actually do it?

Thank you!

Comment: why do you want to do that? Each state should have a different emission distribution. Otherwise, what's the difference between the states?

Comment: I still want to use a Gaussian distribution for each state, but a shared covariance matrix across all of them. I want to do this because I don't have enough data to fully train a continuous HMM, and this paper (http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=4432648&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fiel5%2F10376%2F4432632%2F04432648.pdf%3Farnumber%3D4432648) recommends to use a shared covariance matrix when that is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I have found this great package in C that has an HMM implementation exactly the way I wanted: [Queen Mary Digital Signal Processing Library](http://code.soundsoftware.ac.uk/projects/qm-dsp). More specifically, the HMM implementation is in [these files](http://code.soundsoftware.ac.uk/projects/qm-dsp/repository/show/hmm). So, no need to use GHMM lib anymore.